# fuzzy commitment implemenation to make secure biometric template

Tags: encryption

I want implement some ideas from [an article](http://www.cse.msu.edu/biometrics/Publications/SecureBiometrics/NagarNandakumarJain_MultibiometricCryptosystems_TIFS11.pdf) that is about making secure biometric templates using fuzzy commitment and fuzzy vault. I need to implement just the fuzzy commitment (fuzzy commitment is a biometric cryptosystem).

This schema is explained in mentioned paper in page 6. I implemented fuzzy commitment encoding and decoding in matlab. I'm sure my encoding implementation is correct but I'm not so sure about my decoding implementation. I could not understand the paper's decoding explanation so I used [this paper](http://www.arijuels.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/JW99.pdf) (page 12) for a more understandable explanation of decoding.

My implementation for decoding is: 
(NOTE: best_Binarized_LDA_I_auth_Samp is authentication sample for test)

```
for  ind=1:size(best_Binarized_LDA_I_auth_Samp,1)    
yc=database(ind).yc;
C_prin=bitxor(yc,best_Binarized_LDA_I_auth_Samp(ind,:));
n=power(2,m)-1;
k=n-m;%L in article

K_star=decode(C_prin,n,k,'hamming/binary');
HK_star=whirlpool(K_star);
equality=find((HK_star==database(1).database(ind).hkc)==1);
if length(equality)==512
    disp('succes')
else
    disp('faild')

end
```

end

in this line :

```
K_star=decode(C_prin,n,k,'hamming/binary');
HK_star=whirlpool(K_star);
```

I decode c' to find k* and then I hashed k*, and then if this will is equal to hk, the key should successfully be revealed. When I run this code, however, none of genuine user could not log in successfully. I'm not sure that I find out well fuzzy commitment decoding or not, and I do not know  what is the problem with my code?

Comment: Also, asking for an implementation is likely off topic. Questions about problems you may have implementing it yourself, or about quality of implementation, could be on topic.

Comment: I updated the language in your question and added links to freely available versions of the paper. I hope I didn't change the original meaning. If I did, feel free to edit. I'll reopen and we'll see what the community here says.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but if I were you, I'd contact the authors and see if they can share their source code.

Comment: thank you.I emailed  them ,but unfortunately they do not answer my email :(

Comment: what is your methode for encoding ?? BCH encoder or quoi??
i'am interested with biometric cryptosysteme, my mail: basma_ammour@yahoo.com